# Managing Azure WebApp Deployment Slots and API Manager

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-deployment-slots

I have a WebApp hosted API secured via Azure AD with API Manager in front of it and that is all working nicely.  What I have been trying to do is use deployment slots but of course, that changes the URL endpoint and as such is "unknown" to the API Manager.

When I try to add the staging slot to the API manager as a new API I am finding that the base URL is being stripped of -staging.

I think my approach to this might be wrong but I can't seem to find anything sensible about how to handle slots for APIs behind an API manager.  This article is close to the same issue but is about versioning rather than slots.  [Article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51244756/manage-versioned-api-in-azure-api-manager)

Answer (score 0):

With deployment slots you should mainly use Swap operation (available in WebApps) to swap two deployments. This will swap content and configuration between two slots, so your active URL will remain the same.

If you don't want to swap for some reason, there are ways to resolve this in APIM. You could create a revision of your API and update Web service URL to point to another slot, and then change active revision to emulate swap.

Or you could simply update Web service URL on an API whenever you want to point it to another slot.