# Facing error while accessing the APIM Url with 3443 port in browser

Tags: azure-functions, azure-api-management

I created one APIM in Azure portal and mapped with Azure Function.

When I tried to access the APIM URL in Browser  https://XXX.Azure.net:3443 it showing the below error message

```json
"error" : 
{ 
"code": "MissingorIncorrectVersionParameter", 
"message": "API version query parameter is no specified or was specified incorrectly. 
Supported versions: 2014-02-14-preview, 2014-02-14,2015-05 15,2016-07-07,2016-10-10,2017-03-01,2018-01-01,2018-06-01-preview, 2019-01-01,2019-12-01-preview, 20 12-01,2020-06-01-preview, 2020-12-01,2021-01-01-preview, 2021-04-01-preview, 2021-08-01,2021-12-01- preview, 2022-04-01-preview, 2022-08-01,2022-09-01-preview 
Example query param format: api- version-SupportedVersion",
 "details":null}}
```

How to disable this error message and How to disable unwanted ports

I created Azure APIM and mapped Azure function inside the APIM

APIM URL :  https://xxxxx.azure.net

This url is opend for multiple ports like 8080,3443,443

I am not able to find the option for disabling the port

and when i tried to access the URL like below

https://xxxx.azure.net:3443

it showing below error

```json
"error": 
{ 
"code": "MissingorIncorrectVersionParameter", 
"message": "API version query parameter is no specified or was specified incorrectly.
Supported versions: 2014-02-14-preview, 2014-02-14,2015-05 15,2016-07-07,2016-10-10,2017-03-01,2018-01-01,2018-06-01-preview, 2019-01-01,2019-12-01-preview, 20 12-01,2020-06-01-preview, 2020-12-01,2021-01-01-preview, 2021-04-01-preview, 2021-08-01,2021-12-01- preview, 2022-04-01-preview, 2022-08-01,2022-09-01-preview 
Example query param format: api- version-SupportedVersion", 
"details":null}}
```

Answer (score 0):

> "code": "MissingorIncorrectVersionParameter",
> "message": "API version query parameter is no specified or was specified incorrectly.

This error comes when Versioning is not defined properly or called properly in the Azure APIM API's URL:

[image]

If you have created the versions in APIs of the APIM and testing that URL, you have specified the version number and, in the format, how you have given during creation of Versions and how you specified to the API URL.
[image]

Refer to this SO [51244756](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51244756/manage-versioned-api-in-azure-api-manager) for more information.

Comment: I am not adding any Version details in my APIM.

Comment: Just created one Azure function and mapped that function inside the APIM.

Comment: Access/Browse the APIM URL with mapped Function API Name